# Why does MSBuild maintain a hold on a file?

Tags: msbuild

I've got the following MSBuild script:

```
<Copy SourceFiles="$(AdminPath)\web.config" DestinationFiles="$(AdminPath)\tmpweb.config" />
<TransformXml Source="$(AdminPath)\tmpweb.config" Transform="$(AdminPath)\web.$(Configuration).config" Destination="$(AdminPath)\web2.config" />
<Copy Sourcefiles="$(AdminPath)\web2.config" DestinationFiles="$(AdminPath)\web.config" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" />
<Delete Files="$(AdminPath)\tmpweb.config;$(AdminPath)\web2.config" />
```

However, although web2.config is deleted, tmpweb.config is not "because it is being used by another process" (error MSB3061).

How do I get around this?

I've tried copying the file as described in [this blog post](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2011/09/14/using-custom-webconfig-transformations-in-msbuild) but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using v10 of the publishing tasks. I should have used v12.

For future reference using the following:

`<UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll"/>`

Answer (score 0):

It's not the MSBuild who's locking the file, but the TransformXml task and it's mighty annoying under certain deployment strategies. You can try workarounds from the [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/562200/transformxml-task-locks-config-file-identified-in-source-attribute), personally I wrap it in a custom task via either `TransformXml` task class or `XmlTransformation` class directly which gives an added benefit of extra flexibility, eg logging via `IXmlTransformationLogger`, ie downgrading certain warnings to debug messages to keep the log less noisy.

Comment: I was using an older version of the transformxml. The one with the bug that locks the file. I'm now using the later version that doesn't.